# close a window opened by javascript on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

I open a new window using javascript. Once loaded and the user has done what I need them to do, the opened window then calls a function from the main window, which closes the opened window, taking the user back to the main, original window.

This works fine on desktop - but not on mobile. I can see the opened window runs the function successfully by alerting some info, but the standard .close() function doesn't seem to work. My code looks like:

Main window:

```
var auth_window;
auth_window = window.open(dropbox_auth_url , 'Dropbox Authorization', auth_window_options);

function open_dropbox_picker(access_token){
    alert('back to main window?')
    if(auth_window){
        alert('closing')
        auth_window.close();
    }

    dropbox_access_token = access_token;
    get_dropbox_list_json();
};
```

Opened window:

```
 var url = window.location.href;
 var dropbox_access_token = url.split('#access_token=').pop().split('&').shift();
 window.opener.open_dropbox_picker(dropbox_access_token);
```

both of the alerts on the main menu show, and if I manually close the opened window, I can see by the data on he main window that get_dropbox_list_json() has also worked successfully.

So, how can I close the opened/popup window on mobile?!